# Structures and linked list accessing.

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
typedef struct{ 
    int a;
} cool;

cool x;

(&x)->a = 3;
x.a = 4;
}
```

I was wondering if the (&x)-> a does the same thing as the x.a. I coded both of them up, and it seemed that both of them changed the value of x.a. I know it must be a pointer on the left side of ->, but the (&x) seems to work without problem. Printing out x.a works for both of them, and gives me the correct answer. I looked up a lot about pointers, linked list, and structures and am still not able to find out the answer. Would it be possible to get an explanation? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `->` operator expects a pointer on the left hand side. `&x` returns the address of `x` so it satisfies that requirement (even if it is totally redundant). To think about it another way...

```
cool *y = x;
y->a = 3;
```

The `.` operator expects a [stack allocated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) struct on the left hand side. `x` is that, so `x.a` works fine.

You can also go the other way, if you have a pointer `y` you can dereference it with `*y` and use `.` on it: `(*y).a`. This is also totally redundant.

Comment: Everything makes great sense until the last sentence. I am not fully understanding that. Thank you for the answer to the rest of it. Makes perfect sense for that part.

Comment: @Cole if you already have a pointer, you can dereference it with `*`, e.g., if `y` is a `cool *` (pointer) you can get to the `cool` value with `*y` and so you could do `(*y).a` to get the same value as `y->a`

Comment: @sigmavirus24 would (&y).a be the same as y->a? If so, why?

Comment: No, because `&y` is the address of a pointer. Or, a "pointer to a pointer to ...". You can use either `*` or `->` with pointers. A pointer-to-pointer cannot use `->` because it doesn't point to a struct or union, which is what `->` is for. You would have to use `*` to *dereference* the pointer, like `(*(&y))` (which is just `y` again), and then you could use `->`, like: `(*(&y))->a`

Answer (score 1):

The `&` prefix operator returns the *memory address* of whatever object you put it in front of.

This means that you have to put it in front of objects that actually *have* a memory address. For example, literals and temporary expression results don't necessarily have an address. Variables declared with `register` storage class don't have an address, either.

Thus:

```
int i = 5;
&i;  // works

&5;  // Nope!

&(i + 1); // Nope!

&i + 1;  // Works, because &i has higher precedence than +1.
```

So what does the address of an object give you? It is a *pointer* to the object. This is how you can do *dynamic memory allocation* using the *heap*. This is where functions like `malloc()` come in. And this is how you can build arbitrarily large data structures.

In C, *arrays* are represented as pointers. So arrays and pointers are often used interchangeably. For example:

```
char buffer[100];  // array
strcpy(buffer, "hello"); // strcpy is declared to take (char *, const char *)
```

The opposite of the *address_of* operator is the `*` *dereference* operator. If I declare a pointer to something, I can get "what it points at" using this syntax:

```
int i = 5;
int *pi = &i;  // pointer to int. Note the * in the declaration?

i + i; // 10
i + *pi;  // Also 10, because pi "points to" i
```

In the case where you have an aggregate type like a `struct` or `union`, you would have to do something like this:

```
struct {
    int a;
} s;

s.a = 5;

/* ??? */ ps = &s;  // pointer to s

s.a;  // 5

(*ps).a; // Also 5, because ps points to s.

ps->a;  // 5, because a->b is shorthand for (*a).b
```

This only works, of course, if you have a pointer to an object that CAN use the `.member` and that has an appropriately named *member.* For example, you can't do this:

```
i = 5;
pi = &i;

pi->a;  // WTF? There is no i.a so this cannot work.
```

If you have a pointer, you can take the address of it. You then have a pointer to a pointer. Sometimes this is an array of pointers, as with the `argv` array passed to `main`:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]);
int main(int argc, const char **argv); // Effectively the same.
```

You can do weird stuff with pointers to pointers:

```
int i = 5;
int j = 100;


int * pij;

for (pij = &i; i < j; ) {
    if (i & 1) {
        *pij *= 2;
        pij = &j;
    } 
    else {
        i += 1;
        *pij -= 1;
        pij = &i;
    }
}
```

Note: I have no idea what that code does. But it's the kind of thing you can wind up doing if you're working with pointers.